# JTable focus on entire row instead of cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Is there any way to force a JTable to focus on entire rows instead of individual cells? I'm not talking about the row selection highlight, only about the focus border which I'd like to include all cells on the focused row.

**UPDATE:**

Table with non-editable cells and delete-row-functionality:

```
public class TableTest {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        int rows = 20;
        int cols = 2;
        String[] headers = { "Column 1", "Column 2" };
        String[][] data = new String[rows][cols];

        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++)
                data[j][k] = "item " + (j * cols + k + 1);

        JTable table = new JTable();

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers) {
            // Disable editing of the cells
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        table.setModel(tableModel);
        table.setShowGrid(false);
        table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0,0));

        // key binding to remove rows
        InputMap inputMap = table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
        ActionMap actionMap = table.getActionMap();
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0), "REMOVE");
        actionMap.put("REMOVE", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();     
                for (int i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    tableModel.removeRow(rows[i]);
                }
            }
        });

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {}
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

"Focus border" on selected row:

[image]

"Focus border" with no rows selected:

[image]

"Focus border" in Windows LAF:

[image]

I want this "focus border" to include all cells of the row (when visible).

Below is the same code but I've added part of @camickr 's code:

```
public class TableTest {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        int rows = 20;
        int cols = 2;
        String[] headers = { "Column 1", "Column 2" };
        String[][] data = new String[rows][cols];

        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++)
                data[j][k] = "item " + (j * cols + k + 1);


        // ADDED CODE
        JTable table = new JTable() {

            private Border outside = new MatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK);
            private Border inside = new EmptyBorder(0, 1, 0, 1);
            private Border border = new CompoundBorder(outside, inside);

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
                // Add a border to the selected row
                if (isRowSelected(row)) jc.setBorder(border);
                return c;
            }
        };


        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers) {
            // Disable editing of the cells
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        table.setModel(tableModel);
        table.setShowGrid(false);
        table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0,0));

        // key binding to remove rows
        InputMap inputMap = table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
        ActionMap actionMap = table.getActionMap();
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0), "REMOVE");
        actionMap.put("REMOVE", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();     
                for (int i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    tableModel.removeRow(rows[i]);
                }
            }
        });

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {}
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This adds a border around the entire row (but with no left/right inset to include all cells). This is not the "focus border/rectangle", it is a border that appears around selected row only. When I delete a row the selected row is cleared and the focus border reappears.

Note that I do **not** want to hide the focus border (I know how to do it), I want to keep it functioning like that but to include all cells of the row instead of one cell when it becomes visible.

Comment: What is intended meaning of the entire row focus? Where the keyboard input should go? Or it is just a display issue and you want to display `FocusBorder` around row as whole?

Comment: I just want to display FocusBorder around the entire row. The cells are non-editable btw.

Comment: No. The focus is there to show where keyboard input should go when you start typing. Doing what you want goes against convention and is not designed into framework. The only option would be drawing focus border yourself in custom cell renderers for each column. This tricky to get right in the general case as columns can be rearranged by user. Much simpler solution would be to not use JTable at all and use JList with a single custom cell renderer instead.

Comment: @Andrew Butenko thanks I'll take a look at JList

Answer (score 3):

> I just want to display FocusBorder around the entire row.

Take a look at [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/).

It shows one way to put a Border on the row instead of individual cells.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it's not exactly what I'm looking for since this is not the actual focus border. I tried it and it works only for selected rows. When there is no row selected but the focus border is visible it still occupies one cell instead of all.

Comment: @AndroidX, `it works only for selected rows.` - Exactly only a single row can ever accept input at one time so the Border will only ever be on a single row.  I don't see a border on a single cell with the code I suggested. There is no such thing as a "FocusBorder" for a row. As has already been mentioned, only a cell can accept input so only a cell can have an Border that looks like a dotted line.  You need to clarify your question by posting a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the behaviour you want to change.

Comment: If you don't like the "red border" then you supply your own "focus border". I just showed you a concept. You are allowed to customize the concept to meet you actual requirements.

Comment: I didn't provide an SSCCE because I think this is basic JTable functionality. Anyway I've edited my question.

Comment: `There is no such thing as a "FocusBorder" for a row. As has already been mentioned, only a cell can accept input so only a cell can have an Border that looks like a dotted line.` I think this answers my question... "you can't do it". If you include it in your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: `"you can't do it".` - no that is not the answer. You "can" customize the Border for the row to make it look like the focus border of an individual cell. `When I delete a row the selected row is cleared and the focus border reappears.` So you modify the logic to check all the columns of the current row being rendered. If any of the columns in the row is the true "focus Border" then you just paint your custom focus border for the cell.

Comment: In any case the answer should be "accepted" since you have your answer one way or the other.